# In Flutter, scrollbar with letter hint

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollbar

I have a known size list of items and their widgets have specified sizes as well. I managed to get an ever-showing, draggable `Scrollbar` in my app. Is there any way for me to show a hint for my user as to what is currently the first letter for the first showing widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use existing packages that offer this feature, like:

https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_list_scroll_view

https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_scroll_view

or you can follow some existing guides that explain how to implement your own version:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/flutter-alphabetical-indexed-listview-84fcf570b9e1

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGgizUoyeYY&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com